# HasOneOrMany.php line 221 error in laravel when I try to upload an image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm working on a laravel project, I want to allow users to post images but I get this error:

> FatalThrowableError in HasOneOrMany.php line 221: Type error: Argument
>   1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::save() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, none given, called in
>   my statuses controller.

Here's my statuses controller code:

```
class StatusController extends Controller {
public function postStatus(Request $request){
    $this->validate($request, [
        'status' => 'required|max:250',
        ]);
        Auth::user()->statuses()->create([
            'body' => $request->input('status'),
            ]);

    if($request->hasFile('image')){
        $image = $request->file('image');
        $filename = Auth::user()->username . time() . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($image)->fit(300,300)
            ->save(public_path("/uploads/images/" . $filename ));


        $statuses = Auth::user()->statuses();
        $statuses->image = $filename;
        $statuses->save();
    }


    return redirect()->route('home')->with('info', 'Status posted.');
}
```

In my user model I have this

```
    public function statuses() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Status', 'user_id');
}
```

any suggestions please?

Comment: The line `$statuses->save()` is expecting a model to be given. So you should be doing  `$statuses->save(StatusModelHere)`

Comment: Thanks response, but I'm kinda new to laravel, what model should I put in there exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
$statuses = Auth::user()->statuses();
```

You get a Collection of statuses. You don't need to do this because you created a new status on line 6. Change your code to:

Line 6:

```
$status = Auth::user()->statuses()->create([
    'body' => $request->input('status'),
]);
```

Remove line 16:

```
$statuses = Auth::user()->statuses(); //Remove this line
```

And Change:

```
$status->image = $filename; //Note we changed the var name to the created above.
$status->save();
```

Comment: I have no idea what happened but it actually worked, thaanks man!

Comment: Hahaha. I can explain:
When you call `statuses()->create()` you **create** a new `Status` and save it in the `$status` variable. For study purpose, use `var_dump($status)` before assigning the image and `var_dump($status)` after assigning and you'll see it changes the `Status`. Then you just save it.